# How avoid denormalization

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity `Category` and an entity `CategoryType` that are in many to many relationship.
In a third entity `Request` I have to save the `Category` and `CategoryType` of this `Request`.
My pseudo-code for `Request` is something like:

```
@Entity
class Request(
id: Long,
title: String,
description: String,
category_id: Long,
category_type_id: Long) {

@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne
category: Category

@JoinColumn(name = "category_type_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne
category: CategoryType
}
```

I think it's a bad idea design in this way my entity because there is a functional dependency (I guess) between these 2 id (`category_id` and `category_type_id`), so I'm not respecting 3rd normal form.
So I tought I can create an entity that represent the many to many relationship and save the id of this new entity in the table.
For example:

```
@Entity
class Request(
id: Long,
title: String,
description: String,
category_to_type_relation_id: Long) {

@JoinColumn(name = "category_to_type_relation_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne
category: CategoryToCatTypeRelation
}

@Entity
CategoryToCatTypeRelation(
id: Long,
category_id: Long,
category_type_id: Long)
```

Do you think this could be a viable solution?
Or there is a better way to avoid denormalization?

Comment: Can you give an example of data that goes into Category and CategoryType ?

Comment: Sure! Both `Category` and `CategoryType` will have simply 'id' and 'name' columns.
For example: 'Category1' with id '1' and 'CategoryType1' with id '2'

Comment: I was hoping for a real example. My concern is you might not need both Category and CategoryType

Comment: I could have 2 `Category`: "Programming languaces" and "Graphic card".
I could have 3 `Category Types`: "New", "Old", "Broken"
Obviously the `Category` programming language can be "new" or "old" but cannot be "broken", instead a graphic card can be "new", "old" and "broken".
So, when someone create a new `Request`, that `Request` could be about a New Programming language or an Old programming language, but not a Broken PL.
That's why I would avoid putting both the ids, becaouse someone can create Request that does not make any sense

Comment: I see this way: using the first approach you have the flexibility to not-pre configure the valid combinations of `CategoryToCatTypeRelation`. But it sounds like you want to do some validation on user-submitted data before submitting it. For the second approach, you need to pre-configure all the valid data in CategoryToCatTypeRelation before the user can save `Request`. Both approaches look fine to me but the decision should be based on the use-case/requirements.